# How does one avoid SVN errors on api manager worker nodes at server startup

Tags: svn, wso2, wso2-api-manager

The general consensus since carbon 4.2.0 if not before has been to remove the ../../repository/deployment/server directory and then start the worker node.

This gives the expected error

```
The synapse.xml location ././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default doesn't exist
```

Then you have to restart the worker node in order to avoid the error.

Another known tweak to this is to just remove the subversion .svn directories with something like

```
find <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/ -type d -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Following the new release of API Manager version 2.0.0; has there been any work done on providing a better solution to these workarounds ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is fixed in 2.0.0 either. Please create a ticket in WSO2 API manager JIRA.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER